# Dynamically create structure names in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, structure

I would like to create a dynamic structure name using a string, here's my structure:

```
Structure foo
    dim lorem as string
    dim ipsum as string
    dim dolor as integer
    dim sit as integer
End structure
```

On creation

```
dim bar as new foo 'Bar is temporary, it holds the information and then change its name [I know that's not working like that, imagine] (See below)
bar.lorem = "Random string here"
bar.ipsum = "But random doesn't exist, right ?"
bar.dolor = 42
bar.sit = 1337

bar.name = "Foobar_" & var 'integer/string/variable here (lets say var is "Cookie")
```

So when i want to use the structure, i can do something like that:

```
msgbox("Secret cookie code =D >> " & callFunctionThatGetsStructureByName("Foobar_Cookie").sit.tostring)
```

I get callFunctionBlahblah.sit -> 1337

Is this possible ? i hope i'm clear in my explanations. If i can get any help, thanks :)

Comment: Sounds like you just want a dictionary of keys and your structure.

Comment: I'm going to search for that, thanks, i'll post if i got news

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is just a [`Dictionary(Of String, foo)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

Just create a new dictionary:

```
Dim myDictionary = new Dictionary(Of String, foo)()
```

Then you can add items to it by key:

```
dim bar as new foo 'Bar is temporary, it holds the information and then change its name [I know that's not working like that, imagine] (See below)
bar.lorem = "Random string here"
bar.ipsum = "But random doesn't exist, right ?"
bar.dolor = 42
bar.sit = 1337

myDictionary.Add("Foobar_" & var, bar)
```

Then you can later retrieve it from the dictionary like so:

```
Dim retrieved = myDictionary("Foobar_Cookie")
```

Comment: This is clever and perfect, just what i need, thanks a lot ;) Here's your cookie ;)